# I need some help manipulating a string in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, class, constants

I have this string 'custom_controller'.

I need to get it to this 'CustomController'.

It's from the required file name and the class name inside is needed.

To cut to the chase, the code is [here](https://github.com/adamgamble/brain_rack).

It is a project that comes from the Rack tutorials on Github. [rack/rack/wiki/Tutorials](https://github.com/rack/rack/wiki/Tutorials)

But rather than just name them custom.rb and class Custom, I want it more like a Rails app without requiring Rails or any of the gems that come with Rails except maybe Rack.
This is not a Rails app. This is not even a Sinatra or Padrino app. It's just a home brew web framework using Rack.

Comment: The statement "I want to make it work more like Rails would." infers that you want a solution that behaves like Rails, but does not require Rails. It would be worth explicitly stating that you want a solution that doesn't require Rails, in your question as a number of answers have been given that have missed this point.

Comment: Yes and thanks for deleting the Rails tag. My bad. Some good answers though. Thanks everybody. Please take a look at the app in the link. You might enjoy it.

Comment: Why not just use the rails implementation [String#camelize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize)

Answer (score 2):

You can use plain ruby to build your own `camelize` method.

```
def camelize(string)
  string.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join
end
```

Comment: or `map(&:capitalize)`

Comment: I like the split method because it returns an array and if you look at the code, it originated from an array.

Answer (score 2):

This would also work:

```
"custom_controller".gsub(/_*([a-z]+)/i) {$1.capitalize}
```

And is closer to the way [Rails handles this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f2489f493b794ee83a86e746b6240031acb8994e/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb#L66). I'd suggest you look at the Rails code as it also handles some variations on the simple case you quote. For example, how would you handle name spaced controllers `'foo/custom_controller'`?

Answer (score 0):

The desired result is just the camel case representation of the source string. You can try to use `'custom_controller'.camelize`.

Comment: `camelize` is a `String` method provided by rails. So, you need to add in your answer what gem needs to be required.

Comment: @ArunKumar rails was mentioned in the tags. So I presumed it.

Comment: @31ply If you look at his [Gemfile](https://github.com/adamgamble/brain_rack/blob/master/Gemfile), you won't find `rails`. Looks like he added a wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could get it as 'CustomController' by doing following :

```
'custom_controller'.split('_').collect{|x| x.camelize}.join
```

If you want to use this as class you could do following :

```
'custom_controller'.split('_').collect{|x| x.camelize}.join.constantize
```

**constantize** is basically used to convert any string to class.
But I am not sure whether that works for controller. You can read more about it [here](http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize)

Read more about **camelize** [here](http://apidock.com/rails/String/camelize).